# Scaling website to be printed on a single page

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a html page which includes a rather large SVG (varies in size, but it can be up to 2000 pixels wide and high) among with few other html elements.

When I invoke a print dialog using `window.print()` or otherwise SVG is split over several pages. Is there a javascript, css or any other solution to gracefully scale the website so it would fit on a single page.

Note: SVG is dynamically generated with raphaeljs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can control the zoom with javascript much the same as if you were to hold `CTRL and + or -`

Give this a try on whatever trigger you wish:

```
document.body.style.zoom = .5;
```

Not sure if it will affect the printing part though, as I don't print pages. Worth a try.

If that doesn't work, do a transform! Wrap your entire page in a group tag after the `<svg>` tag.

```
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<g transform="scale(.5)" >
your entire svg page here!
</g>
</svg>
```